# Is it OK to check if (this == NULL) in C++ in order to terminate a detached thread's execution?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, this, destructor

Lets say I create an object of a class X. When class X is constructed, it creates a detached thread on a function that loops indefinitely. I would like to terminate (or break out of) this detached thread when class X is destroyed. Is this possible? Is there a better way of achieving this?

**For example:**

```
class X
{
public:
    X(){
        startThread();
    }
    virtual ~X(){

    }

    void myThread()
    {
        cout << "start of myThread()" << endl;

        int loop = 0;
        while(true)
        {
            //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
            ++loop;
            cout << "loop # " << loop << endl;
            if(this == NULL){
                break;
            }
        }

        cout << "end of myThread()" << endl;
    }

    void startThread()
    {
        std::thread example(&X::myThread, this);
        example.detach();
    }
};
```

Comment: No it is not OK. By the time "this" is NULL, "this object does not exist. because "this" is a pointer to the object that you are in. it will never be NULL unless the object does not exist. which mean the object is already destroyed via destructor. By "does not exist", I mean that you will get Seg fault or maybe it will work but can make Seg fault later. because this is pointing to a place in memory that has this object but this is free memory that anyone can use.

Comment: Er, `this` is an address, it won't change just because you destruct what's at that address...

Comment: Ah I see. In this example, after myThread is detached, it seems that it will run infinitely (even after the object class X is destroyed). Is there a way for the thread (myThread) to break out of its' while loop, given that the object X has been destroyed?

Comment: @user1456962 Making the thread exit after the object has been destroyed is unsafe because you could access data that doesn't exist anymore before the thread realizes the object was destroyed. You have to make the thread exit before the object is destroyed. You could potentially also get away with something like: make sure it is notified to and stops accessing data before the object is destroyed and then exits on its own, potentially after the object has been destroyed, though I am not sure if this is safe if the thread is a non-static member function.

Comment: @user1061392, thank you for this response! It makes sense. this should never be NULL since it is after all just an address. By the time it's destroyed, this will point to some other object and give a segfault later.

Comment: @Marc , thanks! You're right, the address of "this" will not change.

Comment: @user2802841, thanks! You're right. The thread might access data that doesn't exist anymore... I need to make the thread exit before the object is destroyed...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deleting the X object while the thread is still running will definitely not work; you will end up crashing and corrupting data a lot, as the still-running thread tries to access the now-freed data.

What your main thread (i.e. the thread that spawned the myThread thread) needs to do instead is:

1. Somehow tell the thread to voluntarily stop looping and exit (e.g. by changing the value of a std::atomic<bool> that myThread checks periodically, or sending a byte on a socket that myThread is receiving on, or something like that)
2. Call join() on the thread object.  join() will block until the thread has fully exited.

Once join() returns, you can then safely go ahead with deleting the X object.

(Side note: if you do the above steps in the X class's destructor, that will be thread safe only as long as you never subclass X, or (if you do subclass X) the thread never accesses any data members from the subclass (e.g. if the thread never calls any virtual methods).  That is because there will be a race condition between the time the subclass destructor gets called (while the internal thread is still running) and the X destructor gets called (to stop the thread) during which the thread could access now-freed data from the subclass's layer)

Comment: You might add that there is no way that `this == NULL` will be true in the given code. There are two reasons for this: 1. `this` is usually implemented as a local variable in the function, so no legal operation will ever be able to modify it from another thread. 2. The standard says that it is undefined behavior if `this` is a null pointer, so the compiler may completely optimize away the `if() {}` statement.

Comment: @Jeremy, thank you for this information! Could I simply create a static bool variable somewhere and have the thread to voluntarily stop looping/exit based on that variable's value? (I'm not too familiar with "volatile boolean" and "atomic" values). Is this what an atomic value is designed for? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic

Comment: "e.g. by setting a volatile boolean" - please don't perpetuate the myth that volatile variables have anything to do with concurrency! The only right way to do this in standard c++ is with a `std::atomic<bool>`!

Comment: @user1456962 atomic values are specially handled in such a way that they can be accessed by multiple threads without any serialization and still give meaningful results.  (The special handling makes accessing them somewhat less efficient, but without it you can get unexpected behavior on some hardware; e.g. thread B never "seeing" the update that thread A made)